# Ansible variables between playbooks

Tags: windows, unix, statistics, ansible, set

I am trying to build a workflow where first playbook runs on Windows hosts, set some variable with all host names that it’s being executed. Second playbook supposed to read this variable and create a directory in Unix with windows hostname.

Tried using `set_stats` in first playbook, but variable is getting concatenated with all hostnames and one directory is getting created on Unix with big string.

Any workarounds or suggestions to achieve this.

Playbook runs on Windows

```yaml
- name: set hostname in a variable  
  set_stats:  
      data:  
        current_hostname: "{{ ansible_hostname }}"  
      per_host: no
```

Playbook runs on Unix:

```yaml
- name: Creates UNIX directory  
  file:  
    path: "{{ ARCH_DIR_LOC + current_hostname + '/'}}"  
    state: directory  
    mode: 0777
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I was able to script as below and working for me:

```
  vars:  
    win_host_names: []  
  tasks:  
  - name: prepare list  
    set_fact:  
      win_host_names: "{{ win_host_names }} + [ '{{ ansible_facts.hostname }}' ]"  

  - name: set stats 
    set_stats:  
        data:  
          current_hostname_list: "{{ win_host_names }}"  
        per_host: no
```

Comment: Why is this solution accepted?  The answer passes variables between tasks in the same play.  I don't THINK this answers the question.  Actually I see same person who asked also answered.

Answer (score 6):

There is no way to keep variables between Ansible runs. But there is a trick: you can save variables into yaml/json file (at localhost) and then use `include_vars` to load them.

saving:

```
- copy:
    content: '{{ my_variable|to_json }}'
    dest: foo.json
  delegate_to: localhost
```

loading:

```
- include_vars:
    file: foo.json
```

Comment: Thanks George. Still trying to go with same approach as workflow can run concurrent for different groups at same time, depending on a local file can be problem during these concurrent executions. set_stats is helping to have persistent variable, but only problem is handling multiple values. If set_stats or any other module can create a global variable with complex data structure like an array or list will help in systematically breaking it in second playbook for completing the task.

Comment: You can use different names for those variables, and you can use 'critical sections' (one host at a time) with `serial:1` at play level.

Comment: You should be saving vars to facts for a dummy host, then access across playbooks.  Search for that in SO for example